# Request body goes missing when application is deployed to Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a `net6.0` Razor pages app that is running fine locally, but doesn't work when deployed to Azure. It seems that POST bodies are going missing.

Here's some middleware...

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("BodyLogger");
        if (!context.Request.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        }
        if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("POST cl=" + context.Request.ContentLength.ToString());
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("BodyLogger try");
                string body = "";
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("BodyLogger using");
                    body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

                _logger.LogInformation($"BODY ok (length {body?.Length ?? 0})" + (body ?? "(null)"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("BODY error " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
```

...and what appears in ApplicationInsights.
[image]

What's going on?!

**Updage**

Even more strangely: it still doesn't work if it's deployed to a *different* Azure Web App resource, and this middleware

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/post")
    {
        if (!context.Request.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        }
        //context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string body = "";
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        //context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync("The body was: " + body);
        return;
    }
    await next.Invoke(context);
});
```

works both as the first and the last middleware.

I've noticed that *absent* from the ApplicationInsights logs are the Kestrel messages

```
Connection id "0HMOAORGGN3ES", Request id "0HMOAORGGN3ES:00000003": started reading request body.
Connection id "0HMOAORGGN3ES", Request id "0HMOAORGGN3ES:00000003": done reading request body.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in some cases my custom `ITelemetryInitializer` for ApplicationInsights (turned off in development) was reading the request body.